# Resource has no available deserialization method

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Using Django I'm getting the following error when making a POST to my API:

**The format indicated 'text/plain' had no available deserialization method. Please check your `formats` and `content_types` on your Serializer."**

I have tried adding the  `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the form but the error is the same. I'm thinking maybe this is a API serializer issues?

Any idea's?

**This is the AJAX:**

```
 $.ajax({
                  url: '/api/v1/rewards/campaigns/',
                  type: 'POST',
                 dataType: "json",
                  beforeSend: function (request) {

                      request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
                  },
                  data: $('#registration').serialize(),
                  success: function(data, textStatus) {
                      console.log('success');

                  },
                  error: function(errorThrown){
                     // data = JSON.parse(errorThrown.responseText);
                      console.log(errorThrown);
                  }
              });
```

This is the resource it is posting to:

```
class urlencodeSerializer(Serializer):
    formats = ['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist', 'urlencode']
    content_types = {
        'json': 'application/json',
        'jsonp': 'text/javascript',
        'xml': 'application/xml',
        'yaml': 'text/yaml',
        'html': 'text/html',
        'plist': 'application/x-plist',
        'urlencode': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }

    def from_urlencode(self, data, options=None):
        """ handles basic formencoded url posts """
        qs = dict((k, v if len(v) > 1 else v[0] )
                  for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(data).iteritems())
        return qs

    def to_urlencode(self, content):
        pass

class CampaignCreateResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rewards/campaigns'
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=CampaignForm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` to your `$.ajax()` call to indicate the content type of the request data.

`dataType` argument specifies the format of the *response*, not the *request*!